# Get the list of cities, suburbs with relations from Overpass-turbo

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I'm struggling to build a mini database set for with the following structure

```
{countryId, governorateId, cityId}
```

The idea is:
I need to find all admin_level=4 for Egypt, then for each result, get the cities|suburb|town

Example:
Cairo: ['Nasr City', 'Fifth Sattelment',...etc.]

Where Cairo = Governorate, 'Nasr City' = Suburb

What i have so far:

```
[out:csv(::id, 'place', 'name:ar', 'name:en')][timeout:25];
// fetch area “Egypt” to search in
{{geocodeArea:Egypt}}->.searchArea;
// gather results
(
  node[place~"city|town|suburb"](area.searchArea);
);
// print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

which gives me the list, but without relations, so i have no clue which `suburb` is inside which `city`

Answer (score 0):

When you write that query without filtering the columns it should return it will return a node like such:

```
<node id="21320911" lat="-33.9783333" lon="25.5874001">
    <tag k="is_in" v="Port Elizabeth,Eastern Cape, South Africa"/>
    <tag k="name" v="Walmer"/>
    <tag k="place" v="suburb"/>
    <tag k="sagns_id" v="62090"/>
    <tag k="source" v="sagns"/>
    <tag k="wikidata" v="Q61356595"/>
  </node>
```

So, to extract the relations you can add the "is_in" column to the query so that it can look something like so...

```
[out:csv(::id, 'name', 'is_in', 'place')][timeout:25];
// fetch area “South Africa” to search in
{{geocodeArea:South Africa}}->.searchArea;
// gather results
(
  node[place~"city|town|suburb|street"](area.searchArea);
);
// print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

and that should show your suburb and the city including the country. Eg:

```
@id name    is_in   place
21320910    Newton Park "Port Elizabeth, Eastern Cape, South Africa"    suburb
21320911    Walmer  "Eastern Cape, South Africa"    suburb
21320912    Mill Park   "Eastern Cape, South Africa"    suburb
```

On my result set, it sometimes returns the city and sometimes doesn't...Hopefully this helps out.

Comment: unfortunately i tried the "is_in" but it's always empty. Not a single node returned a value!